# Was Calev a convert?

Tags: sources-mekorot, conversion-to-judaism, parashat-shelach

I seem to recall reading or hearing somewhere that Calev was a convert to Judaism, originally being a Chiti, and that's why his descendants are called "Celavi." (For example, [Shmuel I 25:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a25.htm).)

Was Calev a convert? I tried looking in Rashi where he first shows up, in [Parshas Shelach](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9941/jewish/Chapter-13.htm), but he says nothing on the matter.

What's even more intriguing is that if Calev was a convert, then why is he listed as the spy to represent Sheves Yehudah in [Bamidbar 13:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9941/jewish/Chapter-13.htm)?

Comment: The fact that he's a spy for Yehuda is a pretty ironclad proof that he isn't a convert.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Is it?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60318/was-caleb-a-foreigner-non-isralite - I guess this answers my question.

Comment: Re last question - why can't a convert be a spy?

Comment: @DanF - The question is not whether a convert can be a spy or not, the question is as to why, if Calev was a ger, was he chosen to be the spy for Sheves Yehudah?

Comment: Well, OK. But what would be the problem with that? He's Jewish, now. Maybe Caleb was the most qualified person from that tribe.

Comment: @danf converts aren't from tribes.

Comment: I re @DoubleAA: Converts aren't assigned a tribe.

Comment: I got it, now! While at that time, people knew what tribe they were from, perhaps, there was an automatic assignment of all converts to the tribe of Yehuda. (Ruth, e.g., seems to be assigned to Yehuda.) It may be similar to the current concept that we are called *Yehudim*.

Comment: @DanF - The difference between Ruth and Calev is that Ruth was a woman, meaning she could marry into the tribe. When you're working with men and tribal affiliation, it becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: @DanF Ruth was never part of Yehuda. Her child was part of Yehuda because of their father. Tribe-ness always follows the father.