# What do we know about Yefuneh?

Tags: historical-figures

(Inspired by [Who was Yehoshua Bin Nun's father?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/who-was-yehoshua-bin-nuns-father/20255#20255), as well as the riddle "What was Kalev ben Yefuneh's father's name?" "Chetzron!")

Looking for sources that an actual person named Yefuneh actually existed, and what we know about him/her (perhaps someone suggests Yefuneh was a woman).

I'm aware that the opinion of many Mefarshim is that of [Gemara Sotah 11b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.11b.23?lang=bi), that Kalev's father's name was actually Chetzron, but I'm looking for other opinions.

Comment: Good place to start: http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Divrei_HaYamim_I/4.15#e0n7

Answer (score 1):

Gershon Gold answered the related question [Was Caleb a foreigner (Non-Isralite)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60318/was-caleb-a-foreigner-non-isralite) 
as follows:

> Divrei Hayomim 2:18 says that Caleb was the son of Chetzron. Radak
>   there says that this is Caleb ben Yefune. Radak says he was known as
>   ben Yefune since he turned away from the Meraglim's blasphemy of the
>   land.
>
> Ibn Ezra disagrees and says his father's name was Yefune and his
>   grandfather's name was Kenaz.

So we have the view of the Ibn Ezra.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caleb) acknowledges two people: Caleb, son of Jephunneh  and Caleb, son of Hezron.

> Caleb, son of Jephunneh (Numbers 13:6) is not to be confused with
>   Caleb, great-grandson of Judah through Tamar (1 Chronicles 2:3-9).
>   This other Caleb was the son of Hezron, and his wife was Azubah (I
>   Chronicles 2:18,19).

Josh Waxman in his [parshablog](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2014/06/was-calev-ben-yefuneh-same-person-as.html) maintains that contradictions between Divrei Hayomim and the rest of Tanach are resolved at the level of derash and therefore

> ...on the level of peshat, we need not say that this is the same
>   Calev, even though both are from the tribe of Yehuda.

Comment: Hm... Ibn Ezra, or Wikipedia? Who should I trust?