# PTIJ - Raui Leachilas Meraglim

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89353/16354) answer about being Mi Yodeya cookies being ראוי לאכילת כלב, which got me wondering:

Does the concept of something being Chametz on Pesach depend on just whether or not Kalev wold eat it, or would [any of the Meraglim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Spies) have the same din?  I'm not sure about this because Kalev and Yehoshua were the good spies, so maybe it's just Yehoshua too? Please enlighten me.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rest of the meraglim had problems with large serving sizes, to the point where there were so sure that everyone else would agree with them and brought them to show to klall yisrael. Calev, and only Calev, davened and worked on himself to judge food based on its own value, and ignore its size. (Any Yeshiva bachur would be like Calev by large serving sizes, but might think that small amounts of food aren't worth his time. Yehoshua was the quintessential Yeshiva bachur, the first one in and the last one out...)

Answer (score 3):

The prince of Asher was Setur the son of Mikey. Since [Mikey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Mikey) hates *everything*, nothing would be considered something that could be eaten by him, and it would be a גזרה שאין רוב הציבור יכול לעמוד בו (a decree no one would be able to fulfill). Our sages wisely restricted this to Caleb, who is [always hungry](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%90).

Comment: You've been watching a few too many old cereal commercials. Also, Mikey liked only Life cereal. Considering that's the only thing that he eats, it's a wonder that he wasn't diabetic as a kid.

Answer (score 1):

You know the expression, "Like father, like son". A hint to this from a Jewish concept can be found in Rash"i on [Breishit 25:19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=320&hilite=).)

Who was Calev's father? יפונה which means, "he would turn away from". Specifically, Calev's father would turn away from eating cookies, because he was satisfied with the *mahn* that they had daily, as well as the quail that they had at night. He couldn't fathom eating anything else, certainly not cookies - esp. computer cookies.

Calev was like his father, so the cookies were definitely not ראוי לאכילת כלב.

The only other spy this same halacha could apply to is  סתור בן מיכאל of the tribe of Asher. סתר means "hidden", and we know that Chametz must be hidden on Pesach. So, only if you are an "Asherite", you would be forbidden to eat these cookies, because סתור didn't eat these on Pesach.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88460/what-do-we-know-about-yefuneh

Comment: Ah! You have a bias linking to your own question, my friend. And, that question has no answer, yet, so you haven't proven that Yefuneh didn't exist. BTW, you might want to place a bounty on that question. "Like father like son" has no exact Jeiwsh source, directly. But see Rash"i's comment at beginning of parshat Toldot suggesting that Yitzhak looked just like Avraham. It's a "hint" to that idea.